# MATE Dock Applet does not show all program windows

Tags: 16.04, mate, applet

I am using MATE Dock Applet v.80 (GTK2) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the Mate desktop. It works fine, but some programs do not get listed in the applet. Mostly, portable apps are affected, but others as well.

Some example programs which do not show up are:

- LibreOffice Calc (was already pre-installed in my distribution)
- JabRef (used portably)
- NetBeans (used portably)
- Simplenote (used portably)
- Atom editor (used portably)
- Eclipse Java (used portably)
- Eclipse JavaEE (used portably)
- ...

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I recommend to ask this question on https://ubuntu-mate.community/  .

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the V0.88 from https://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/mate-dock-applet (install the .deb file).

I had a lot of issues like that in previous versions but now it's better (although there is still a few applications not showing up)

Comment: If it is better, did your problem really get solved?

Comment: @vinícius-valente Do you use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: No, I didn't get solved my issues.
I'm running Ubuntu Mate 18.04 and here's an example when I'm running Sozi.
You can see that the WindowList application show the window but the mate-dock-applet not. [Ubuntu MATE running sozi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhUBx.png)